# Message timestamp and commit_timestamp in Kafka's __consumer_offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm currently working on an application that partially relies on Apache Kafka (version 2.2.0). One thing I have to do is to keep track of what (and more importantly when) other consumers commit their current offsets. As far as I can tell, just using the Java client, there is no way to get the associated timestamps for the committed offsets because [`AdminClient`](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html)'s [`listConsumerGroupOffsets`](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#listConsumerGroupOffsets-java.lang.String-) method eventually leads to an [`OffsetAndMetadata`](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/OffsetAndMetadata.html) object, which does not include a timestamp. So instead, I simply started reading the messages from the `__consumer_offsets` topic. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Now, if one reads the messages in `__consumer_offsets` directly, then one all of a sudden has two timestamps. One is the timestamp attached to the actual commit message and the other one is the `commit_timestamp`, which is part of the message's content. My first thought was that one of these is probably set by the broker and the other one might be set by the client that committed it (also, if you look at `/config/topics/__consumer_offsets` in ZooKeeper, it doesn't specify a `LogAppendTime` message timestamp, so one could assume that it just uses the default). Alas, a quick experiment with manually shifted system times shows that both are actually set by the broker. What's more, they don't always agree (the message's timestamp is sometimes slightly ahead of the `commit_timestamp`). I've tried to dive into the Kafka code to understand exactly what's going on but it is rather convoluted and I'm not familiar enough with it to quickly get a good grasp. So here are my questions:

1. Why is the message timestamp in `__consumer_offsets` automatically `LogAppendTime` even though that's not explicitly specified? Is it just that the producer that is used to send the commit message leaves the timestamp empty?
2. Why do the message timestamp and the `commit_timestamp` included in the message not agree? I seem to recall having read somewhere that it used to be possible to explicitly set the `commit_timestamp` and thereby manually control the retention of the committed offset.
3. More importantly: Is there any reason to use one over the other? For example, if it's still possible to set the `commit_timestamp` manually, it would make much more sense to use the timestamp attached to the message.

I understand that this is a highly specific question and probably of little importance to most. But until now, I was always able to understand what's going on in the background by using Google and looking at Kafka's source code; yet, this one has me a bit stumped. So any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The metadata of an OffsetAndMetadata can contain whatever you want. In fact, this is one part of what Confluent Replicator uses to ensure consumer failover in disaster scenarios

Comment: @cricket_007 Ah, good point. However, in the metadata, I would only be able to include a client-side timestamp. What I am interested in here (and what is provided by the two timestamps I mentioned) are broker-side timestamps.

Comment: I haven't spent too much time looking the consumer offset  message generation, but I'm not personally aware of being able to explicitly set the time. The messages are still formed via a ProducerRecord, though, and a client generates them (the consumer group coordinator, I believe), so it's not completely a "broker timestamp"

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you very much for your insights. First off, isn't the consumer group coordinator a broker (in contrast to the group leader)? The messages are certainly created by a client but the timestamps seem to be broker generated. To test this, I ran a Kafka broker with a system time that was shifted by 5s, which was what I saw in the obtained timestamps as well.

Setting the timestamp manually seems to have been part of the Kafka protocol as seen [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-OffsetCommit/FetchAPI).

Comment: Hmm. So you say you're using Kafka 2.2, but those docs say that the timestamp of the offset commit request have been removed since 0.9... Did I read that correctly?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, that confused me as well at first. I am using Kafka 2.2 and the commit_timestamp is definitely still there. You can easily check this by opening a console consumer on the `__consumer_offsets` topic or looking at line 970 of [this](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/coordinator/group/GroupMetadataManager.scala). I guess the documentation is just about the API, not the internals. That's why I suspected that internally, if you specify a retention time (as per the API), still the commit_time is modified.

Comment: And by "API", I mean "protocol"

Comment: It seems that the documentation I linked to is not kept up to date (I didn't pay attention to the date stamp below its title). As is obvious from the documentation in the [source](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/resources/common/message/OffsetCommitRequest.json), one cannot manually specify a retention time anymore. So, my question stands: What's the `commit_timestamp` good for?

Answer (score 0):

I think latter time stamp is expiration time.
Can you please try following to make sure?

Set internal topics accessible by setting parameter `"exclude.internal.topics=false"` in `consumer.config`.

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh  --consumer.config /tmp/consumer.config \
     --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
     --topic __consumer_offsets
```

I could see result as follows:

```
[mygroup1,mytopic1,11]::[OffsetMetadata[55166421,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1502060076305,ExpirationTime 1502146476305]
[mygroup1,mytopic1,13]::[OffsetMetadata[55037927,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1502060076305,ExpirationTime 1502146476305]
[mygroup2,mytopic2,0]::[OffsetMetadata[126,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1502060076343,ExpirationTime 1502146476343]
```

I don't have specific version as you mentioned in your question installed in my machine, so please check it in your end.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think you might be using an older version of Kafka. As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/coordinator/group/GroupMetadataManager.scala) (lines 950-974), the expiration time used to be there but not anymore. In my case, it's just reported as `None`. What I'm talking about is the timestamp of the message itself. Usually, you can see this by passing `--property print.timestamp=true` to the console consumer but for whatever reason, it doesn't work for the `__consumer_offsets` topic on my machine.